# php, проверить существование файла

Tags: php

у меня есть файл, его название `bring-it-44453OH_terms_29.05.2020.pdf`

я хочу проверить его существование по таком название `bring-it-44453OH_terms_`

Это возможно?

Comment: Самый простой способ: `glob('/path/to/dir/bring-it-44453OH_terms_*.pdf');`

Answer (score 1):

```php
function fileBringExists() {
    return count(glob('/path/to/dir/bring-it-44453OH_terms_*')) > 0;
}
```

```php
if(fileBringExists()) 
    echo "Он здесь!";
else
    echo "Нет его...";
```

Так же вы можете использовать `glob` чтобы получить его реальное название

```php
function getBringFilename() {
    $files = glob('/path/to/dir/bring-it-44453OH_terms_*')
    if(!count($files))
        return false;
    return $files[0];
}
```

```php
$bring = getBringFilename();
if ($bring)
    echo "Он здесь: ". $bring;
else
    echo "Нет его...";
```